# can tf.identity used to copy Variables in memory (Tensorflow)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to keep a copy my Tensorflow variables to avoid having to keep track of the best epoch run using a file saver in order to reduce my I/O operations. It is a way to keep the best variable state in memory. Essentially, I would like to do something like this:

```
# Creating the graph and training batches.
# Training loop.
for i in range(10):
    loss = self.train_iteration(batch)
    if loss_improved(loss):
        copy_var = tf.identity(self.var_to_copy)

# Copy back the copy_var into var_to_copy
var_to_copy = tf.identity(copy_var)

saver = tf.train.Saver(var_to_copy)
saver.save(sess, variables_file_path, write_meta_graph=False, write_state=True)
```

My questions:
- is tf.identity the right op to use or should I use tf.variable.
- Will the tf.train.Saver() work as expected given that the output of tf.identity is not a Variable.
- Is there a cleaner way to do this?